# Shooting Targets: On mouse click -> Leave Bullet Hole.gif

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, targets, aim

I have a section on my website that has several aim targets for visitors click to shoot at. I am using `cursor: crosshair` for the section. I want to make it so that When my visitor clicks anywhere in the targets section I want to leave an animated `bullet_hole.gif`

I guess the command for the code would be within `div` container onmouse click  create a `div` at the click Location and then delete the `div` after 5 seconds.

How do I write the javascript/jQuery code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the location of the click within a container you can get the `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties from the event object passed to the jQuery click handler. You can then create an absolutely positioned `div` at that position which contains the bullet hole image to be displayed. From there you can use a timer to remove that div after 5 seconds. Something like this:

```
$('#target').click(function(e) {
    $('<div />').addClass('bullet-hole').css({
        top: e.offsetY - 5,
        left: e.offsetX - 5
    }).appendTo('#target');
    setTimeout(removeBulletHole, 5000);
});

function removeBulletHole() {
    $('#target .bullet-hole:not(:animated):first').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rx04r6z8/)

Comment: I copied  your code and it doesn't work.

I copied the .bullet-hole style and pasted it in my css stylesheet

I copied the javascript and pasted it in my header.php

Inside <script type="text/javascript"></script> tags

I changed #target to #workcontainer 

Which is the #DIV id - I want the bullet holes in

and it still does not work on my website.

I am not sure why

www.prismasites.com

Scroll down until you see the targets